# Prevent triggering jQuery functions at specific screen widths for menu/nav system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

I'm new to using jQuery and have tried to code a basic menu system that at screen widths greater than 480px works by hovering the mouse of the li tag to expand the submenu, and at widths less than 480px by clicking the li tag to expand the submenu.

I've tried to include the use of Modernizr's ability to detect media queries, however as you'll see from my attempt, it fails miserably:

[Working example.](http://novicecoder.co.uk/priestley/).....hover over the li tag named 'Properties'

The issue is clearly something to do with the code not picking up screen resizing as it works at > 480px and < 480px if you refresh the browser at the correct widths, but the functions still try to trigger when you resize the browser!!

My code:

```
// Main nav dropdown animation

$(document).ready(function() {
  function doneResizing() {
    if(Modernizr.mq('screen and (min-width: 481px)')) {

        $("#sub-menu").hide();

        $("#show-investment-type-nav").hover(function() {
            $(this).find("#sub-menu").stop(true, true).slideDown("fast");
        }, function() {
            $(this).find("#sub-menu").stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
        });

    }
    else if(Modernizr.mq('screen and (max-width: 480px)')) {

      $("#sub-menu").hide();

      var next_move = "show";

        $("#show-investment-type-nav").click(function() {

            $('#sub-menu').slideToggle(100);

            if (next_move === "show") {
                $("body").addClass("nav-active");
                $("#site-nav #icon").empty().html("&#59236;");
                $("#site-nav #nav-margin-down").animate({"margin-top": "163"}, 100);
                next_move = "hide";
            } else {
                $("body").removeClass("nav-active");
                $("#site-nav #icon").empty().html("&#59238;");
                $("#site-nav #nav-margin-down").animate({"margin-top": "0"}, 100);
                next_move = "show";
            }
        });
    }
  }

  var id;
  $(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(id);
    id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 0);
  });

  doneResizing();
});
```

Any help on why this is happening would be great, it'll help me learn!!

Cheers guys!

Comment: You aren't unbinding your click handler. You could do that, but it would probably be better to define the click event outside of the resize handler, and check the screen width inside the click handler.

Comment: @JasonP so include if(Modernizr.mq('screen and (max-width: 480px)')) {} after the click handler??

Comment: Move the click handler out of the resize handler, and copy that if statement inside the click handler.

Comment: @JasonP had a go at that, but can't seen to get it to work. Can you leave a quick example please?? I've fixed the issue at sizes greater than 480 by using $("#show-investment-type-nav").unbind("click").hover(function() {} but that seems to be more of a hack

Comment: You could try unbinding the hover events when the screen is < 480px. And vise versa for > 480px. Or use diff trigger elements which can be toggled via css media queries

Comment: Thanks for the input @TimWax, I've included my hack in the answers below, but this is due to me not understanding the nature of unbinding an event...can you shed some light on the solution please??

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try and see if it works. I moved the click handler out of the resize handler. Binding events in events is tricky, and generally isn't necessary. I also had to move `next_move` to put it in the global scope. Adding the value to the menu element using `data()` might be a better option:

```
var next_move = "show";

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#show-investment-type-nav").click(function () {
        if (Modernizr.mq('screen and (max-width: 480px)')) {
            $('#sub-menu').slideToggle(100);
            if (next_move === "show") {
                $("body").addClass("nav-active");
                $("#site-nav #icon").empty().html("&#59236;");
                $("#site-nav #nav-margin-down").animate({
                    "margin-top": "163"
                }, 100);
                next_move = "hide";
            } else {
                $("body").removeClass("nav-active");
                $("#site-nav #icon").empty().html("&#59238;");
                $("#site-nav #nav-margin-down").animate({
                    "margin-top": "0"
                }, 100);
                next_move = "show";
            }
        }
    });

    function doneResizing() {
        if (Modernizr.mq('screen and (min-width: 481px)')) {
            $("#sub-menu").hide();
            $("#show-investment-type-nav").hover(function () {
                $(this).find("#sub-menu").stop(true, true).slideDown("fast");
            }, function () {
                $(this).find("#sub-menu").stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
            });
        } else if (Modernizr.mq('screen and (max-width: 480px)')) {
            $("#sub-menu").hide();  
            next_move = "show";
        }
    }

    var id;
    $(window).resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(id);
        id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 0);
    });

    doneResizing();
});
```

Comment: http://novicecoder.co.uk/priestley/ ....the fruits of your labour. It's a step closer...but there's still a strange issue with the click event for widths < 480px?? Thank you very much for this, I'm guessing it's basic stuff :)

Comment: Also, by using data() do you simply mean changing the value depending on the state of the click event?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to of fixed the issue, but may be more of a hack than a fix!!

```
var next_move = "show";

$(document).ready(function () {

  // Touch device fix to prevent submenu being shown during initial load
  $('#sub-menu').css("display","block");

    $("#show-investment-type-nav").click(function() {

      if (Modernizr.mq('screen and (max-width: 480px)')) {
        $('#sub-menu').slideToggle(100);
        if (next_move === "show") {
          $("body").addClass("nav-active");
          $("#site-nav #icon").empty().html("&#59236;");
          $("#site-nav #nav-margin-down").animate({"margin-top": "163"}, 100);
          next_move = "hide";
        } else {
          $("body").removeClass("nav-active");
          $("#site-nav #icon").empty().html("&#59238;");
          $("#site-nav #nav-margin-down").animate({"margin-top": "0"}, 100);
          next_move = "show";
        }
      }
    });

  function doneResizing() {
    if (Modernizr.mq('screen and (min-width: 481px)')) {

      // Hide submenu
      $("#sub-menu").hide();

      // Reset margin for li tags if screen expanded whilst nav open
      $("#site-nav #nav-margin-down").css("margin-top","0");

      $("#show-investment-type-nav").hover(function() {
          $(this).find("#sub-menu").stop(true, true).slideDown("fast");
      }, function () {
          $(this).find("#sub-menu").stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
      });
    } else if (Modernizr.mq('screen and (max-width: 480px)')) {

      // Fixes issue on touch device when you touch away from expanded submenu...this took forever!!!
      $('#sub-menu').slideUp(100);
      $("#site-nav #nav-margin-down").animate({"margin-top": "0"}, 100);

      // To make sure if nav expanded, so next_move ="hide", hover event doesn't hide() submenu
      if (!Modernizr.touch) {
        $("#show-investment-type-nav").hover(function() {
          $("#sub-menu").hide();
          if (next_move === "hide") {
            $("#sub-menu").show();
          }
        });
      }

      next_move = "show";
    }
  }

  var id;
  $(window).resize(function () {
    clearTimeout(id);
    id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 0);
  });

  doneResizing();
});
```